# FIX (Financial Information eXchange) with Mule

Tags: mule, fix-protocol

As we find that FIX is an opensource contribution (http://ricston.com/blog/transport-mule-fix/) to Mule, we were keen to find if anyone has tried FIX connector on Mule Cluster environment, has anyone used FIX connector with mule version 3.4.2 and with Mule Cluster Server? Any comments/issues, Thanks.

Comment: This is a wrong question ? Your answer depends on which FIX engine you are using and how you intend to combine mule with your engine. There isn't a correct answer for this.

Comment: can you please explain why you think there cannot be a correct answer for this? I am simply asking if someone has used fix connector on mule cluster server.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by a FIX connector ??

Answer (score 0):

The original FIX transport does not work with Mule 3, but there is an upgraded version available through Ricston:

http://ricston.com/blog/fix-transport-mule-3/